# upload image from user input, pass to ajax, and return image with response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, input

I am passing a photo that the user uploads from their computer or phone.

html:

`<input class="button" type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" 
 id="upload-button" name="cameraInput">`

I get that image, and pass it to my AJAX call in order to send it to the API. I am trying to just pass the original image uploaded, but I always get and error: "coyote1.jpg:1 GET MYAPP.com/coyote1.jpg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

jQuery:

```
var uploadImage = function() {
      var uploadBtn = $('#upload-button');
      uploadBtn.change(function(event) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        formData.append('sampleContent', file);$.ajax({
          url: 'MY API ENPOINT,
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Authorization':
              'Bearer <MY TOKEN>',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          },
          data: formData,
          processData: false,
          contentType: false
        }).done(function(res) {
          var introArticle = $('#intro');
          var htmlCard = introArticle.append($(`<div class="card" </div>`));
          var htmlContainer = htmlCard.append($(`<div class="container"></div>`));
          var htmlImage = htmlCard.append($(`<img src="${file.name}")}" style="width:100%"/>`));
)};
```

It is trying to look inside my app for the photo, but it is from the user. How do I direct it to the right path for the photo?

Answer (score 1):

Use FileReader

```
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        var htmlImage = $('<img src="'+fr.result+'" style="width:100%"/>').appendTo('div#result');
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfqkokmh/)